# Chrome vs Firefox battle - Image overlaying in table cell

Tags: jquery, html, css, google-chrome, firefox

I want to fill table cell with an image and then add smaller, overlayed image to this cell. 
Here's a part of html code:

```
<tr>
    <td width="20%" height="15%"></td>
    <td id="upper_logo" width="60%" height="15%">
    </td>
    <td width="20%" height="15%"></td>
</tr>
```

CSS:

```
html, body {
margin:0px auto; padding:0;
height:100%;
}

body{
    height: 100%;
}
#upper_logo{
    position: relative;
}

#fff{
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
}
```

And JS:

```
function draw() {
    $('#upper_logo').empty();
    var height = $('#upper_logo').height();
    var width = $('#upper_logo').width();
    var src = "http://i.imgur.com/5t1VyaQ.png";
    var src_fb = "http://i.imgur.com/cVUcmwx.png";

    var ob = document.createElement("img");
    ob.setAttribute("src", src);
    ob.setAttribute("id", "ob");
    ob.setAttribute("height", height);
    ob.setAttribute("width", width);
    document.getElementById("upper_logo").appendChild(ob);

    var ob_fb = document.createElement("img");
    ob_fb.setAttribute("src", src_fb);
    ob_fb.setAttribute("id", "fff");
    ob_fb.setAttribute("height", height);
    ob_fb.setAttribute("width", height * 0.376);
    document.getElementById("upper_logo").appendChild(ob_fb);
}

draw()

$(window).resize(function () {
    draw();
});
```

Here's the problem. In Chrome, facebook image is aligned in the cell, but in Firefox this image is aligned in the whole window.
Chrome: [image: chrome] 
Firefox: [image: ff]
Jsfiddle: [click](http://jsfiddle.net/SchJF/5/)

Note that my web dev skills are poor. If there are other ways to do it (I suppose there are), please let me know about them.

Comment: Correct solution here would likely be to not use tables.

Comment: is there a specific reason you are using the scripting to populate that cell with the code as opposed to just marking it up? Is this a dynamic tool?

Comment: I wanted to make that image dependent on window size. I don't have any experience in web dev, so if there are some other options, I'll be glad to read about them.

Comment: Preach @KevinB, Preach!

Comment: Here's the non-table version, :) http://jsfiddle.net/SchJF/7/ with your percentage heights/widths

Comment: To help with some fuel for your thoughts, give this a read, it's pretty interesting: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/83073/why-not-use-tables-for-layout-in-html

Comment: @Kevin B, many thanks. Your version was a great start for me, I made whole page in non-table version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### You have multiple problems going on:

**Making a dynamic array inside of a table is a perfectly feasible option**, but the way you are doing it (`#id` for your image) is going to *ensure that only one of these items actually gets rendered.*

What you need to do is map your **classes** to each individual table cell.

Also, I see you are removing all elements of the `#upper_logo` every single time the screen gets resized, and re-adding the `img` every time. Definitely a no-no.

I don't know the rest of your code, but you could **easily solve this with `CSS`** alone. Responsive design is one of my specialties, and you are going down a path with almost infinite rendering if they decide to resize their browser.

Comment: Hey, @Nicholas, I am really thankful for your suggestions. I solved everything with css.

Comment: If you believe my post provided a working answer, would you please mark as accepted? Thanks :-)